# Execution failed for task app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, annotations

I have written a small annotation processor and added it as a java library in android project. It works fine and generates required file but at the end build fails with exception `app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`. After running the build command from command line with `--info` argument I have found this line causing the problem

```
file or directory 'C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\MyProcessor\app\src\debug\java', not found
```

I don't know how to fix it. Why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by executing my code for only first round of  annotation processing. In second round, it tries to generate the same files again and I get this error.

Comment: How did you do this? "executing my code for only first round of annotation processing" ?

Comment: You will get round information from Processing environment.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        // round completed
        if (roundEnvironment.processingOver()) {
            // processing is complete. 
            return true;
        }
}

Comment: In your process method.